# Dockerizing Nuxt 3 app for development purposes

Tags: docker, dockerfile, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to dockerize Nuxt 3 app, but I have strange issue.

This Dockerfile is working with this `docker run` command:

```
docker run -v /Users/my_name/developer/nuxt-app:/app -it -p 3000:3000 nuxt-app
```

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:16-alpine3.14

# create destination directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app
WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app

# update and install dependency
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git

# copy the app, note .dockerignore
COPY . /usr/src/nuxt-app/
RUN npm install
# RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

# ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
# ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I don't understand why despite mounting it to `/app` folder in the container and declaring `/usr/src/nuxt-app` in Dockerfile it works.

When I try to match them then I get this error:

```
 ERROR  (node:18) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 3)    20:09:42
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

✔ Nitro built in 571 ms                                                                                       nitro 20:09:43

 ERROR  [unhandledRejection]                                                                                        

  You installed esbuild for another platform than the one you're currently using.
  This won't work because esbuild is written with native code and needs to
  install a platform-specific binary executable.
  
  Specifically the "@esbuild/darwin-arm64" package is present but this platform
  needs the "@esbuild/linux-arm64" package instead. People often get into this
  situation by installing esbuild on Windows or macOS and copying "node_modules"
  into a Docker image that runs Linux, or by copying "node_modules" between
  Windows and WSL environments.
  
  If you are installing with npm, you can try not copying the "node_modules"
  directory when you copy the files over, and running "npm ci" or "npm install"
  on the destination platform after the copy. Or you could consider using yarn
  instead of npm which has built-in support for installing a package on multiple
  platforms simultaneously.
  
  If you are installing with yarn, you can try listing both this platform and the
  other platform in your ".yarnrc.yml" file using the "supportedArchitectures"
  feature: https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc/#supportedArchitectures
  Keep in mind that this means multiple copies of esbuild will be present.
  
  Another alternative is to use the "esbuild-wasm" package instead, which works
  the same way on all platforms. But it comes with a heavy performance cost and
  can sometimes be 10x slower than the "esbuild" package, so you may also not
  want to do that.
  
  at generateBinPath (node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1841:17)
  at esbuildCommandAndArgs (node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1922:33)
  at ensureServiceIsRunning (node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:2087:25)
  at build (node_modules/vite/node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1978:26)
  at runOptimizeDeps (node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-3007b26d.js:42941:26)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

I have absolutely no clue what is going on here except architecture mismatch (that doesn't seem to be the case with working version - I'm on MacBook Air M1).

The second issue is that mounting doesn't update the page.

Comment: How do you think that line means? "Specifically the "@esbuild/darwin-arm64" package is present but this platform
  needs the "@esbuild/linux-arm64" package instead."

Comment: I know what it means: I did put `node_modules` in `.dockerignore` file and mounted the folder with my app, but it still doesn't seem to resolve the issue (it woudl if it would use host `node_modules`). Still, the main issue is why the first example works?

Comment: For development purposes, can you just use Node without Docker?  Can you delete the mount entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found the way. The issue was with Vite because HMR module is using port `24678` and I didn't expose it so it couldn't reload the page. This is how it should be looking:

```
docker run --rm -it \
-v /path/to/your/app/locally:/usr/src/app \
-p 3000:3000 \
-p 24678:24678 \
nuxt-app
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-slim
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm install && npm run dev"]
```